# What is this exception in Log4j when shutting down tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, tomcat7

In a web application I use log4j.
I have used a `shutdown` hook to terminate the log manager:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                LogManager.shutdown();              
            }
        });
```

When tomcat shuts down I see the following exception in catalina.out
What does it mean? What is the problem and how can I fix it?

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped
already.  Could not load org.apache.log4j.helpers.NullEnumeration. 
The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for
debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which
caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact. Throwable
occurred: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1587)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.getAllAppenders(Category.java:413)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.closeNestedAppenders(Category.java:226)
        at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.shutdown(Hierarchy.java:467)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.shutdown(LogManager.java:267)
        at com.MyLog4jStarter$1.run(Log4JStarterListener.java:133) Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org.apache.log4j.helpers.NullEnumeration
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.getAllAppenders(Category.java:413)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.closeNestedAppenders(Category.java:226)
        at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.shutdown(Hierarchy.java:467)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.shutdown(LogManager.java:267)
        at de.siemens.icn.hipath.dls.listeners.Log4JInitListener$1.run(Log4JInitListener.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.log4j.helpers.NullEnumeration
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the exception is that some classes (e.g. `NullEnumeration`) are already unloaded.

The proper way of adding a hook to a webapp is to implement `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` and add this code to `contextDestroyed` method. You will also have to register your listener in `web.xml`.

Comment: Ah!!!I have this code in a `ServletContextListener` but in `contextInitialized` not in `contextDestroyed`

Comment: So the shutdown hooks go to `contextDestroyed`?

Comment: Typically yes, unless you have some special needs.

Answer (score 1):

from [here](http://www.jspwiki.org/wiki/StupidQuestions)

It is possible that this is caused by Tomcat unsuccessfully reloading the web application. The app is unloaded, but all threads don't get shut down properly. As a result, when the threads try to run, they get clobbered by the fact that Tomcat has shut down its classloader, and an error is logged. The best fix is to turn off automatic webapp reloading for the application: in Tomcat's server.xml, find the  declaration, and ensure it is set to: reloadable="false"